# JQuery UI Tabs not working

Tags: jquery, tabs

I am using the exact example below from the JQuery website using its built in tabs functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
 });
 </script>



<div class="demo">

<div id="tabs">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
 </ul>
 <div id="tabs-1">
  <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
 </div>
 <div id="tabs-2">
  <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, odio metus gravida ante, ut pharetra massa metus id nunc. Duis scelerisque molestie turpis. Sed fringilla, massa eget luctus malesuada, metus eros molestie lectus, ut tempus eros massa ut dolor. Aenean aliquet fringilla sem. Suspendisse sed ligula in ligula suscipit aliquam. Praesent in eros vestibulum mi adipiscing adipiscing. Morbi facilisis. Curabitur ornare consequat nunc. Aenean vel metus. Ut posuere viverra nulla. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque convallis. Maecenas feugiat, tellus pellentesque pretium posuere, felis lorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
 </div>
 <div id="tabs-3">
  <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, pede vel vehicula accumsan, mi neque rutrum erat, eu congue orci lorem eget lorem. Vestibulum non ante. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce sodales. Quisque eu urna vel enim commodo pellentesque. Praesent eu risus hendrerit ligula tempus pretium. Curabitur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.</p>
  <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, blandit nec, pharetra at, semper at, magna. Nullam ac lacus. Nulla facilisi. Praesent viverra justo vitae neque. Praesent blandit adipiscing velit. Suspendisse potenti. Donec mattis, pede vel pharetra blandit, magna ligula faucibus eros, id euismod lacus dolor eget odio. Nam scelerisque. Donec non libero sed nulla mattis commodo. Ut sagittis. Donec nisi lectus, feugiat porttitor, tempor ac, tempor vitae, pede. Aenean vehicula velit eu tellus interdum rutrum. Maecenas commodo. Pellentesque nec elit. Fusce in lacus. Vivamus a libero vitae lectus hendrerit hendrerit.</p>
 </div>
</div>

</div><!-- End demo -->

<div style="display: none;" class="demo-description">

<p>Click tabs to swap between content that is broken into logical sections.</p>

</div><!-- End demo-description -->
```

However, when I place the JQuery Accordian plugin anywhere in the tabs-1, tabs-2, or tabs-3  element, it stops working correctly, but it works fine in a normal page that doesn't use Jquery. Or any other Jquery doesn't seem to work as its in any of the tabs DIVs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
 });
 </script>
```

is called before the elements even exist. so

either put it all at the bottom of your html just above the ""

or replace

```
 $("#tabs").tabs();
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function (){ $("#tabs").tabs(); });
```

Comment: $(function() { ... }) is a shortcut for $(document).ready(function() { ... }), so that isn't the cause of the problem

Answer (score 0):

What do your includes look like?  Are the paths correct?

On a side note, I used JQuery UI Tabs in a project for a while, but replaced in with plain HTML/CSS after a while.  Here is a great [tutorial](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/tabs/) on writing CSS tabs.  Not even javascript is required.

Sometimes these prepackaged components try to do too much but end up making a very simple task more complex than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

It should work. I have made a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/nhAJz/

having the accordion nested in a tab.
So it is probably a css issue, can you reproduce it using jsfiddle? so that we have exactly your accordion js and css markup?

Answer (score 0):

I just finished this, you can use it at your use. It's not LI or UI Tabs, but it's the same function, just in my own styling of things.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#Tab1').click(function () {
    $('#TheStreets').hide();
    $('#DownTown').hide();
    $('#Underground').fadeIn(300);
    $('#Tab1').removeClass('NonCurrentTab').addClass('CurrentTab');
    $('#Tab2').removeClass('CurrentTab').addClass('NonCurrentTab');
    $('#Tab3').removeClass('CurrentTab').addClass('NonCurrentTab');
});
$('#Tab2').click(function () {
    $('#Underground').hide();
    $('#DownTown').hide();
    $('#TheStreets').fadeIn(300);
    $('#Tab1').removeClass('CurrentTab').addClass('NonCurrentTab');
    $('#Tab2').removeClass('NonCurrentTab').addClass('CurrentTab');
    $('#Tab3').removeClass('CurrentTab').addClass('NonCurrentTab');
});
$('#Tab3').click(function () {
    $('#Underground').hide();
    $('#TheStreets').hide();
    $('#DownTown').fadeIn(300);
    $('#Tab1').removeClass('CurrentTab').addClass('NonCurrentTab');
    $('#Tab2').removeClass('CurrentTab').addClass('NonCurrentTab');
    $('#Tab3').removeClass('NonCurrentTab').addClass('CurrentTab');
});
});
```

Here's the Full Coding at JsFiddle
[Full Coding](http://jsfiddle.net/bbc78/)